# Amazon SQS - How to validate if a queue is a dead-letter queue?

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3, aws-cli, amazon-sqs

As much as I understand, there is no way to validate if a queue is supposed to be a dead-letter queue for another source queue.
For Example, if I have a queue named 'my-queue' which has a dead letter queue named 'dlq-for-my-queue'. I want to validate by API if 'dlq-for-my-queue' is configured as a dlq for 'my-queue'.

I'm asking this because I want to create an automation which configures a dead letter queue for all my queues, but if I do this, it will create dead letter queues for my dead letter queues... which I don't want to happen.

Do you have any tips how can I do this?

Comment: Retrieve a list of all of your queues, and remove the ones that are mentioned in the redrive policy of another queue.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `ListDeadLetterSourceQueues` ([API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/APIReference/API_ListDeadLetterSourceQueues.html)/[Python SDK](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/sqs.html#SQS.Client.list_dead_letter_source_queues)) on the queue in question. If it returns a queue, that queues redrive lists the given queue as its dead letter queue. For example, this can be done with the cli using:

```
aws sqs list-dead-letter-source-queues --queue-url https://sqs.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/<yourDeadLetterQueueURL>
```

This should return the queue that lists this as its dead letter queue.